# Get POST array data to single variable

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, post

I have an array submitted from a POST form:

```
$_POST["items"];
```

In this array, there can be a group of numbers like such:

```
 2873
 2893
 92389
 928
```

Depending on how the user submits the form, 1-50 values can show up in this array. How do I get this all the data in this array like such:

```
$items = "2873,2893,92389,928";
```

Keeping in mind there won't always be four values, and this is a POST array.

## UPDATE

Before commenting and such, this is a POST array! I've received this error:

```
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in trade_confirm.phtml on line 185
```

**CODE**

```
$arrayitem = $_POST["items"];
$comma_separated = implode(",", $arrayitem);

echo $comma_separated;
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: @AbraCadaver, you need to remember this is a POST array, not your average-every-day array. This is what I've tried...

Comment: `print_r($_POST["items"]);` returns what?

Comment: @PedroEstrada better still, `print_r(is_array($_POST["items"]));` returns what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = implode(',', $items);
```

As per the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) documentation.

Be aware that the data type of `$items` is now a [String](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Comment: This will never do. This is a POST array. I've edited the question with what I've tried for an implosion, but I got an error.

Comment: @CarHazy but the `$_POST["items"]` has been posted as an array as per `<input name="items[]" type="text">`, no?

Comment: Actually I have a POST array of checkboxes. You've answered my question, but none of this solves my problem. I'll give you the rep anyway, and I'll use implosion and explosions to re-code things.